# How do I get the latest run from each product number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with products A,B,C,D and each products has been tested 1 time, so the my table as product A run 1, B run 1, C run 1, D run 1, now product A needed a specific test run 1 more time and C run 3 more times so now my tables has A run 1, A run 2, B run 1, C run 1, C run 2, C run 3, C run 4, D run 1.

My attempts so far was separating information into groups then using join from left, right and inner but it keeps pulling the wrong rows of information or adds up the values. I also tried google in attempt to find the best way to tackle this because I'm going to be dealing with a lot of rows of data so I need it be effective and efficient but still no luck.

**So my question is how do I get all the products to show up in a table with only the latest run when they are all currently in the same table ?**

Comment: use `max` aggregate function on run column

Comment: share your data structured...

Comment: When I did that it only gave me product C with run 4, and ignored everything else. I need to have A run 2, B run 1, C run 4, and D run 1

Comment: TAble product ..... columns....|Product| RUN | Result| ...sorry if i'm bad at explaining my situation, i'm new on stack-flow just made this account like 6 minutes ago. still getting use to this.

Comment: PRODUCT TEST_NAME TEST_RUN TEST_RESULTS
A Density 1 10
A Density 2 14
A Surface Area 1 8
B Surface Area 1 9
B Density 1 11
C Density 1 12
C Density 2 14
C Density 3 15
C Density 4 14
C Surface Area 1 7
D Surface Area 1 1
D Density 1 13

Answer (score 0):

Normally a sample of what you have tried or your data structure would be helpful to providing you information, but I think this is what you are looking for.  It looks like you were missing the group by.

```
Select product, Max(run) from table_name group by product
```